# How to reflect the changes done in a Nokogiri::XML::Document object to get reflected in the actual xml file

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am working on a `Nokogiri::XML::Document` object and when I see t using puts , it is reflecting the change but the same change is not reflected in the xml file with which it is related.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("d.xml"))

#Modification in doc.....
puts doc 
#changes are reflected
```

but when I open `d.xml`, no changes

Comment: You are not saving the `doc` to this file, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("d.xml"))

puts doc.to_xml

# or

File.open("new_d.xml", 'w') do |file|
    file.write( doc.to_xml )
end
```